# Remove only 1st page from a LOT of pdf files

Tags: pdf, batch

That's all I have to do: remove only 1st page from a LOT of pdf files...

Please tell me that magic exists.

Comment: Post your solution anyways.  Regardless if others answer.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can do this with a free program called pdftk, available [here](http://www.accesspdf.com/pdftk/#packages).

You can use the following commands to take every PDF in the current directory and copy them to the ‘trimmed’ directory with the first page removed:

```
mkdir trimmed
for i in *pdf ; do pdftk "$i" cat 2-end output "trimmed/$i" ; done
```

Answer (score 20):

This looks like a job for [PdfToolKit](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/). This a command line utility to manipulate pdfs

First, install PDFToolkil, either from the Software Centre or using the command line:

```
sudo apt-get install pdftk
```

Now the command to remove the first page from a normal (non-protected pdf) would be:

```
pdftk original.pdf cat 2-end output outputname.pdf
```

If the pdf is protected you will need to give the passwords to pdftk.

To convert a large number of pdf's you will need to write a small script that takes care of running pdftk for each one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pdf-stapler`](https://github.com/hellerbarde/stapler) for this task.

Example:

```
for i in *.pdf; do pdf-stapler del "$i" 1 t.pdf && mv t.pdf "$i"; done
```

Comment: this is better than pdftk, open source and there are packages for pdf-stapler (on fedora too :P )

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this command line

```
tree -fai . | grep -P ".pdf$" | xargs -L1 -I {} pdftk {} cat 2-end output {}.truncated.pdf
```

Does the job, but of course if the file has more than one page, I tested it, it also works with as many levels of folders you have. Just make sure that you run it a the root of the folder structure. Every folder will have for every pdf file an aditional pdf ending with `.truncated.pdf`

You need `pdftk` and `tree` for this and on Ubuntu Linux you can install it with apt:

```
sudo apt install pdftk tree
```